# Why change the current directory to the parent directory of a relative symlink before creating it

Tags: symlink, ln

From the manual of coreutils, for `ln`

> When creating a relative symlink in a different location than the
>   current directory, **the resolution of the symlink** will be different
>   than **the resolution of the same string from the current directory**.
>   Therefore, many users prefer to first change directories to the
>   location where the relative symlink will be created, so that
>   **tab-completion or other file resolution** will find the same target as
>   what will be placed in the symlink.

The string stored in a relative symlink is determined completely by the source pathname and the target pathname, both specified as command line arguments to `ln`.

I don't see how the current directory gets involved. So 
I don't quite understand the reason why many users prefer to change the current directory to the parent directory of a to-be-created relative symlink before creating it. Could you rephrase or give some examples? Thanks.

Comment: They **change directories to the location where the relative symlink will be created**, so that their point of view when they create it, is the same as that when it is used. This reduces confusion. also when using tab completion, it makes it easier, as tab completion will not work otherwise.

Comment: Still confused. The string stored in a relative symlink is determined completely by the source pathname and the target pathname, both specified as command line arguments to `ln`.

I don't see how the current directory gets involved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things to remember:

1. `ln -s` (without `-r`) stores the target name **literally as you pass it to it**
2. if you pass a relative target, it resolves **relatively to the link name**, **not** your current working directory

**Example:**

I'm in `/home/user/d0` and I want a link to `/home/user/file` so I do:

```
ln -s ../file .
```

`../file` is a valid path from `d0`.

Now  if there's a subdirectory `d1` (`/home/user/d0/d1`) and I want to place a link to `../file` (`/home/user/file`) there without changing dirs, I need to do:

```
ln -s ../../file d1/
```

because the relative path needs to be **relative to the link name**, not my current working directory. `../../file` (probably) resolves to nothing relative to `d0` (unless there's a file named `/home/file`), so I won't get autocompletion for it which might make the operation more error prone.

So I change into `d1` first:

```
cd d1
ln -s ../../file .
```

and now `../../file` makes sense relative to both the current directory and the link name; autocompletion kicks in, and I get my assurance I've got the right name.

GNU `ln` has a `--relative|-r` flag which makes this easier by saving you from having to compose these relative paths manually. With it, you can use a path relative to the current directory or an absolute path, and it'll relativize it relative to the link name (as it needs to be).

Answer (score 8):

If you did

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
ln -s ../../etc/passwd /tmp/foo
```

Then access `/tmp/foo/passwd` would convert to `/tmp/foo/../../etc/passwd` - ie `/etc/passwd`

If you did

```
mkdir /var/tmp/foo
ln -s ../../etc/passwd /var/tmp/foo
```

Then access to `/var/tmp/foo/passwd` would convert to `/var/tmp/foo/../../etc/passwd` - ie `/var/etc/passwd`

So you can see the "relative symlink path" is resolved differently, depending on where the link is saved.  The current directory you run the `ln` command in is not involved at all.

To avoid this confusion some users will change their current directory before creating the symlink

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
ln -s ../../etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Ubuntu. After running `ln -s ../aaa/bbb /tmp/output/`, `readlink output/bbb` outputs `../aaa/bbb`, instead of `/tmp/output/../aaa/bbb` in your example. Do I miss something?

Comment: `readlink` just reads the link, it doesn't _resolve_ the link.  Use `realpath` to expand all the links and relative paths.

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely correct. What goes in the symlink is exactly what is specified on the command. But the manual tries to say, that the symlink will be interpreted relative to the location of the link, so the user should take care to make the link correctly.

Take an example:

```
/tmp/test$ mkdir bar
/tmp/test$ ls -l foo/aaa 
-rw-r--r-- 1 itvirta itvirta 0 Jul  4 00:37 foo/aaa
/tmp/test$ ln -si foo/aaa bar/
```

The file is there, just where we think it is, so one might assume that the link works now. Except it doesn't, since the link is interpreted relative to its location, not relative to where I was when creating it.

```
/tmp/test$ cat bar/aaa 
cat: bar/aaa: No such file or directory
```

If I go to the target directory before creating the link, I'm sure to not get confused:

```
/tmp/test$ cd bar
/tmp/test/bar$ ls -l ../foo/aaa 
-rw-r--r-- 1 itvirta itvirta 0 Jul  4 00:37 ../foo/aaa
/tmp/test/bar$ ln -si ../foo/aaa  .
```

However, to add to the confusion, when creating a hard link, the way to point to the target file is exactly the obvious way that didn't work when creating a symlink:

```
/tmp/test$ ln foo/aaa bar/
```

There reminder is there because symlinks point by name, not by the file identity (inode) like pretty much all other actions would. Moving to the target directory first aligns both cases, and reduces the chance of human miss-ups.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `ln -sT abc/fgh mno/xyz` it stores `abc/fgh` in a new file mno/xyz, and sets the link bit. When you look in `mno/xyz` you will actually look in `mno/abc/fgh`. This matters not (as you say) what directory you are in when you create, or use the link.

However:

They change directories to the location where the relative symlink will be created, so that their point of view when they create it, is the same as that when it is used. This reduces confusion. Also when using tab completion, it makes it easier, as tab completion will not work otherwise.